# How to implement L2-norm pooling in Keras?

Tags: keras, pooling

I would like to add a global temporal pooling layer to my CNN that has three different pooling functions: mean, maximum, and L2-norm. Keras has mean and maximum pooling functions but I haven't been able to find one for L2. How could I implement this myself?

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking for this, there's no such pool out of the box in keras. 
But you can implement it with the Lambda Layer

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K

def l2_norm(x):
    x = x ** 2
    x = K.sum(x, axis=1)
    x = K.sqrt(x)
    return x
global_l2 = Lambda(lambda x: l2_norm(x))(previous_layer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this and there are little information on how to calculate the pooling. If someone are interested in implementing it, see the following comparison:

Max Pooling: get the max value from the NxM cell being assessed and put this as the value of the downsampled matrix for this cell position.

Avg Pooling: Similar to above, instead of the max value, get the average of all value within the cell

L2-Norm Pooling: Similar to above, instead of average, calculate the L2-Norm of the numbers within a cell and then use this number in the target downsampled matrix. Let's suppose we get a cell (kernel size) that is 2x2, which are four numbers. Now suppose these four numbers are 1,2,3,4. The L2-Norm would be sqrt(sum(1<sup>2</sup>+ 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup>). This is the number that goes into targeting cell.